# VB6 application - automatically incremented number check

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm building a small application and I came across an issue that I need to resolve. When I insert a new client into the SQL-SERVER I need to create an ID number to go with the client. I have a value, say - 1000 in a reference table, that gets pulled from the table, incremented by 1, then put back into the ref table, and the value 1001 gets assigned to the client. Before it gets saved to the client, I add 'TOL' to the number - so when save is complete, the ID is TOL1001. The issue I need to resolve is to check the tblClient_TABLE, to make sure that ID TOL1001 doesn't exist already before doing the insert for a new client.

I'm not really sure where I should do it, because on SAVE, I call the function that increments the number, assigns TOL to it and stores the value in an invisible textbox, so when I do my insert, it just pulls the value from the textbox... 
    strSQL = "INSERT into tblClient_TABLE (ID) values ("txtIDnumber.text")

I obviously have more data to insert, it's just i'm struggling with finding a logic way to check for the already existing ID.

Thanks for any ideas, help!

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and read about sql injection. Your approach sounds like a textbook example. You need to parameterize your queries. To solve your issue you should look into using EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is able to use identity columns (=autoincrement). So, if you insert a new record, an identity column will get the next value (you can rely on the uniqueness).

How do you get this number? The insert statement has (for mssql) an "output inserted" clause, and if you use ado with executescalar you get your inserted id.

The SQL command (add the vb6 code for ado command you must)

```
INSERT INTO [TABLENAME] ( [COL1], [COL2] ) OUTPUT INSERTED.MYID VALUES ( @COL1, @COL2 )
```

... add your Parameter values here ....

```
result = adoCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

(something like that, don´t have VB6 at the office ...)